# How to limit the display of questions in the quiz using json array in android?

Tags: java, android, json, limit

Hey guys I'm developing a quiz where I have 50 questions stored which are accessed using json array and I want to display only 10 questions, my problem is that all those 50 questions are displayed everytime the user will play.Is it possible to limit them if I want only 10 questions to display? After my 10th question  the score class is showed.

Can you guys please help me with this?

```
    List<JSONObject> question = null;

    private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
        try {


            InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
            bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
            StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
            String aJsonLine = null;
            while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                quesString.append(aJsonLine);
            }

            Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
            JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
            quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
                    "Num Questions " + quesList.length());

              question = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
                 int n = Math.min(10, quesList.length());
                 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                     JSONObject questions1 = quesList.getJSONObject(i);
                     question.add(questions1);


                 }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } finally {
            try {
                bReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
            }

        }

    }

    public static JSONArray getQuesList()throws JSONException{

          Random rnd = new Random();

            for (int i = quesList.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
              int j = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
              // Simple swap
              Object object = quesList.get(j);
              quesList.put(j, quesList.get(i));
              quesList.put(i, object);
            }
            return quesList;


    }
}


    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.startquiz);

    try {
        score = getIntent().getIntExtra("score",0);
        items = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displayitems);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayquestion);
        answer1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option1);
        answer2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option2);
        answer3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option3);
        answers = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.QueGroup1);


        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selected);
        next.setOnClickListener(nextListener);

        selected = new int[Question1.getQuesList().length()];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(selected, -1);
        correctAns = new int[Question1.getQuesList().length()];
        java.util.Arrays.fill(correctAns, -1);

        this.showQuestion(0, review);



    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
    }

}

private void showQuestion(int qIndex, boolean review) {
    try {
        JSONObject aQues = Question1.getQuesList().getJSONObject(
                qIndex);
        String quesValue = aQues.getString("Question");
        if (correctAns[qIndex] == -1) {
            String correctAnsStr = aQues.getString("CorrectAnswer");
            correctAns[qIndex] = Integer.parseInt(correctAnsStr);
        }

        question.setText(quesValue.toCharArray(), 0, quesValue.length());
        answers.check(-1);
        answer1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        answer2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        answer3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        JSONArray ansList = aQues.getJSONArray("Answers");
        String aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(0).getString("Answer");
        answer1.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(1).getString("Answer");
        answer2.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        aAns = ansList.getJSONObject(2).getString("Answer");
        answer3.setText(aAns.toCharArray(), 0, aAns.length());
        Log.d("", selected[qIndex] + "");
        if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
            answers.check(R.id.option1);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
            answers.check(R.id.option2);
        if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
            answers.check(R.id.option3);

        setText();
        if (quesIndex == (Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1))
            next.setEnabled(false);

        if (quesIndex < (Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1))
            next.setEnabled(true);

        if (review) {
            Log.d("review", selected[qIndex] + "" + correctAns[qIndex]);
            ;
            if (selected[qIndex] != correctAns[qIndex]) {
                if (selected[qIndex] == 0)
                    answer1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 1)
                    answer2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                if (selected[qIndex] == 2)
                    answer3.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 0)
                answer1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 1)
                answer2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            if (correctAns[qIndex] == 2)
                answer3.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
    }
}


private void setAnswer() {
    if (answer1.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 0;
    if (answer2.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 1;
    if (answer3.isChecked())
        selected[quesIndex] = 2;



    Log.d("", Arrays.toString(selected));
    Log.d("", Arrays.toString(correctAns));

}

private OnClickListener nextListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = correctAns.length;

        if (v == answers){
            if (correctAns[i] == selected[i])
                    {

                        score++;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else
                    {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your answer is wrong..." + correctAns, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
        }


        quesIndex++;
        try {
            if (quesIndex >= Question1.getQuesList().length())
                quesIndex = Question1.getQuesList().length() - 1;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        showQuestion(quesIndex, review);

    }
};
private void setText() throws JSONException {
    this.setTitle("Question " + (quesIndex + 1) + "  out of  "
            + Question1.getQuesList().length());
    items.setGravity(250);
}

public void reload() {
    setAnswer();



Intent intent = getIntent();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
finish();

overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Why areyou sleeping in the main thread for 1 second?

Comment: That is a whole lot of code to scan through. Just post the relevant part if you can.

Comment: @JoxTraex ok..let me update my code...

Comment: @user2079544 do you want the user to get 10 random questions or 10 questions in a specific order.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it would probably be better if you download the entire json response and read only the relevant pieces.

Ideally if you want to have 10 questions and have a total of 50 that means you are going to want to have the 10 occur 5 times. In order to do this, you could just store it all in an ArrayList and then as you get to the next set just offset the position you go to by 10 and then grab those elements and display them and repeat this process until you are out of questions. Or another way would be to remove the top set after each use and just keep reading the top 10 each time.

Keep in mind that as you grab new questions you **MUST** to update the content with the new elements you are reading the the ArrayList.

Comment: plesae show me sample code or just refer me to another link tht is my relted to my question.thanks